# Cant get the right NPM version from the latest nodejs LTS installer

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I use a Windows 10 x64 Pro machine as a development environment.

Today I went to the Node.js site, (nodejs.org/en/download) to get the LTS version which is 8.11.4 for Node and includes npm 5.6.0. This information is visible at the top of the page.

After installation, I did the command "node -v" and actually this gives me v8.11.4 as result. On the other hand the same command for npm "npm -v" gives me version 2.15.10.

What troubles me is that different documentation suggests that the update is done by installing the latest version, which I did, with the result that I have; the wrong NPM version.

I need at least NPM version 3.x or higher. As a lead already explored without success;
- clean installation from the original site by choosing the LTS version, branch x64
- uninstalled the version and reinstalled

Is it a known bug or is there another avenue to explore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is: VS 2017 installs a really old version of NPM. 
By doing the following command in powershell "npm config get prefix" I could see that the prefix was pointing to Microsoft. Then I used the "npm-windows-upgrade" tool to get the installer path for VS. From there I navigated to the bin folder and launched the JavaScript file to start the update.

Answer (score 0):

VS2017 looks to use version 2.15.10.
The path to it is c:users{userprofile}.mpmrc
I just deleted this file and all ran fine (i'm not using VS).